# How do you access route parameters in an AngularJs Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parameters

I have a simple angular example where I can not get the route paramters for the query string in the URL. How do I do this?

Controller:

```
appRoot.controller('RegistrationController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $resource, $routeParams) {

if ($routeParams)
    debugger;


}]);
```

Main Configuration File

```
var appRoot = angular.module('registrationApp', ['ngRoute', 'registration.directives', 'ngResource']);     //Define the main module + dependancies


//Sets up AngularJS module and routes and any other config objects
appRoot
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    //Setup routes to load partial templates from server. TemplateUrl is the location for the server view (Razor .cshtml view) - Frigin amaze-balls
    $routeProvider
        .when('/registration/:inviteToken', { templateUrl: 'registration', controller: 'RegistrationController' })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}])
.controller('RootController', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function ($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (e, current, previous) {
        $scope.activeViewPath = $location.path();
    });
}]);
```

When I browse to something like http://example.org/registration/?inviteToken=2354234 route paramters is alway an empty object. I have also tried http://example.org/registration#/?inviteToken=2354234

One thing maybe worth noting is that http://example.org/registration is the MVC controller

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration, you have specified a route like this:

```
http://example.org/#/registration/2354234
(where $routeParams.inviteToken will be 2354234)
```

If you want to match a URL like this `http://example.org/registration/?inviteToken=2354234`, then you need a different route:

```
/registration/?inviteToken=:inviteToken
```

---

<sub>I am not usre you are aware of this, but the routes you define refer to the path **after** the `#`, unless you are using (and have configured correctly both on the client-side and on the server-side) "HTML 5" mode.</sub>